# No cointegrated relationship accepted in STATA (vecrank)

Tags: stata, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I am using the vecrank command in STATA to identify the number of cointegrating relationships for 2 dependent price series (a and b). The Johansen trace test uses a recursive method (i.e. first null hypothesis = no cointegrating relationship. If rejected, first null hypothesis = 1 cointegrating relationship, etc.). Because I have a total of two price series, there must be either 0 or 1 cointegrating relationships.

The results are showing me that both 0 and 1 cointegrated relationships are rejected. What could this mean? Should it lead me to believe that (because it cannot be more than 1) there exists 1 relationship? Additionally - I have tested for non-stationary and I accepted the null of a unit-root for both a and b.

Below is the code and output:

```
vecrank a b, lags(2) trend(constant) max ic

Johansen tests for cointegration                        
Trend: constant                                    
Number of obs =         244
Sample:  4 - 247                 Lags = 2

                                                     5%
maximum                                      trace    critical
 rank    parms       LL       eigenvalue  statistic    value
  0      6       680.73707           .     25.0038    15.41
  1      9       691.15394     0.08184      4.1700     3.76
  2      10      693.23895     0.01695

                                                     5%
maximum                                       max     critical
 rank    parms       LL       eigenvalue  statistic    value
  0      6       680.73707           .     20.8337    14.07
  1      9       691.15394     0.08184      4.1700     3.76
  2      10      693.23895     0.01695

maximum
rank    parms       LL       eigenvalue     SBIC       HQIC       AIC
 0      6       680.73707               -5.444636  -5.495997  -5.530632
 1      9       691.15394     0.08184   -5.462432* -5.539474* -5.591426
 2      10      693.23895     0.01695   -5.456993  -5.542595  -5.600319
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both 0 and 1 are rejected, you are left with >1. That means there are at least two linear combinations of the variables that are stationary. That means both variables are stationary to begin with.

To convince yourself, you could try Johansen test on a pair of randomly generated i.i.d. series, and you will see that both 0 and 1 are rejected. (I would include an example using Stata code, but unfortunately I am not familiar with Stata.)

Comment: That would makes sense, though I've performed several tests (with various specifications) on both series, always accepting the null hypothesis of a unit root. Do you have any idea on why this would happen?

The other confusion, would be that thethe Hannan–Quinn information criterion (HQIC) and the Aikaike Information Criterion (AIC) both select the rank of 1, contradicting stationarity.

Comment: @Nox, I am not sure whether information criteria can be used for selecting the cointegration rank. I don't know a methodology that would do that. Probably they are just reported as supplementary information.